# Proper way to update WordPress plugin (for updates)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a woocommerce website and I was wondering what is the best way to update plugins (details) and still be able to update the plugin.

For example, I have two plugins that I just want to change the content in them like the currencies in woocommerce writes د.ب  which is in Arabic Bahraini Dinar and I wanted it to be BHD.

Also another example I wanted to change in the wc-vendor plugin the namings instead of calling them vendors I want to call them artists.

I been reading articles about the best methods to update a plugin but I am not sure if they are also valid if I just wanted to change the "Naming" not "functionality"

https://www.seedprod.com/customizing-wordpress-plugins/

Summary: 
I appreciate if you can tell me how to change plugin content and still be able to update it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plugins developed by others, you may have more problem again in the future if the plugins update. Ask the developer or create an issue regarding the problem. Unless you're writing it of your own, you can play the changes locally or create an staging environment. If sound no problem, that's the time you need to replace code in plugins directory.

Comment: Yes, I thought there is a way around to change the content somehow and not get influenced by updates..someone mentioned to me in another forums to use translating plugins "like wpml" which may work out but need to check

Answer (score 0):

I assume, upstream developers are not able or willing to provide hooks for your need.

If you really must modify a plugin, put the plugin source code in a version control system (Git, Mercurial, ...). Make a branch for your changes, and each time a new upstream version comes up, import the upstream version and forward merge your modifications.

Comment: oh I thought we can do the underlying with any plugin specially it is just about changing "content" not functionality. Sorry am new when it comes to plugins editing

Comment: @KhalidAlmoulani Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve, sorry.

Comment: no its ok I am not very good with English.. my question was to change content that comes with plugins like change the word "vendor" to "artist" from multi vendor plugin and still be able to update the plugin. Thanks!